# Content layout alignment between two wrapper elements

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

Basically what im trying to achieve is the following
[currently -> desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oi85.png)

I have a wrapper that displays x amount of cards in a 2 column layout, and each pair's content should be aligned according to the card with the largest content. both cards share the same content layout with the same css.

So any ideas or implementations that could push me in the right direction  are welcome, thanks :) (without using fixed heights in the styling)

Using: React & Sass

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: css grids, here is a good reference : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Answer (score -1):

you can use flexbox. using a fixed height for the inner boxes that doesn't expand and align them at the bottom. The blue text expands, set flex-grow property on it

Comment: i thought about that, but im looking for a solution without fixed heights, thanks though :)

Comment: If you have more than one item with the dynamic height you should loop over all the elements, find the higher and set every node with that height, but you will need to do with js.